# Safari XSLT engine loses namespace on attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, safari, mobile-safari, xslt-1.0

I have an XSLT that matches certain attributes, and puts them in a different namespace. Here is a simplified version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="urn:test:ns1"
    xmlns:ns2="urn:test:ns2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <!-- copy all nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*[starts-with(local-name(), 'test-')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="ns2:{substring-after(local-name(), '-')}" namespace="urn:test:ns2">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is some example input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<hello-world
    xmlns="urn:test:ns1"
    xmlns:ns3="urn:test:ns3"
    rootAttr="stays in implicit namespace"
    ns3:passMe="stays in the ns3 namespace"
    test-someRootAttr="goes into the ns2 namespace, pulls up ns declaration">
    <test
        defaultAttr="stays in implicit namespace"
        test-someAttr="goes into the ns2 namespace"
        ns3:namedAttr="stays in the ns3 namespace">
        Something
    </test>
    <ns3:cat
        defaultAttr="stays in the implicit namespace"
        test-catName="goes into the ns2 namespace"
        ns3:namedAttr="stays in the ns3 namespace">
        a cat
    </ns3:cat>
</hello-world>
```

And here is the expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<hello-world
    xmlns="urn:test:ns1"
    xmlns:ns2="urn:test:ns2"
    xmlns:ns3="urn:test:ns3"
    rootAttr="stays in implicit namespace"
    ns3:passMe="stays in the ns3 namespace"
    ns2:someRootAttr="goes into the ns2 namespace, pulls up ns declaration">
    <test
        defaultAttr="stays in implicit namespace"
        ns2:someAttr="goes into the ns2 namespace"
        ns3:namedAttr="stays in the ns3 namespace">
        Something
    </test>
    <ns3:cat
        defaultAttr="stays in the implicit namespace"
        ns2:catName="goes into the ns2 namespace"
        ns3:namedAttr="stays in the ns3 namespace">
        a cat
    </ns3:cat>
</hello-world>
```

This works fine on Chrome, Firefox, IE 9+, and Android. However on Safari, I get the following output instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<hello-world
    xmlns="urn:test:ns1"
    xmlns:ns3="urn:test:ns3"
    xmlns:ns2="urn:test:ns2"
    rootAttr="stays in implicit namespace"
    passMe="stays in the ns3 namespace"
    someRootAttr="goes into the ns2 namespace, pulls up ns declaration">
    <test
        defaultAttr="stays in implicit namespace" 
        someAttr="goes into the ns2 namespace" 
        namedAttr="stays in the ns3 namespace">
        Something
    </test>
    <ns3:cat
        defaultAttr="stays in the implicit namespace" 
        catName="goes into the ns2 namespace" 
        namedAttr="stays in the ns3 namespace">
        a cat
    </ns3:cat>
</hello-world>
```

Notice that the namespace *declarations* are correct, but the attributes are missing the desired namespace prefix.

All of this code is in a [github project](https://github.com/murrayju/xslt/tree/dev), which is built by [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/murrayju/xslt/builds/86672890) and uses [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/u/murrayju_xslt) to test on different browser/OS combos.

Can I do something differently with my XSLT that would be a more correct way to accomplish this, that might work on all engines? Or is this just a bug in Safari? Any ideas for workarounds would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the Safari result if you apply just the identity template? Is the output identical/equivalent to the source XML document? If the output is correct, what happens when you add a deleting template (with empty body) that matches any attribute with local-name() starting with "test-" ? How can I run an XSLT transformation with Safari or just with its XSLT engine?

Comment: Are you doing the transformation via some javascript, or are you opening the source document with the xslt associated using `<?xml-stylesheet..?>`

Comment: Seems to work fine in Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2) for Windows (x86). Which version are you using?

Comment: Safari 9.0.1 on OS X

Comment: It is being run via JavaScript. I linked the source code in the question, there is a Karma test for this specifically.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev if I remove the 2nd `<xsl:template>` rule and just leave the identity, the output is still wrong (doesn't match the input). The namespace prefixes are still lost from the `ns3` ones.

Comment: Clone my repo, checkout the `dev` branch, build everything with `./build.sh`, then test on Safari with `./build.sh test --only-Safari`

Comment: @murrayju, Then this case is hopeless -- just don't use Safari's XSLT processor, or, if another XSLT processor is available and invocable from JavaScript, use this one.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev of course we could always do the XSLT server side, but that's not the point. I have not been able to find any alternative javascript implementations to run as a shim... do you know of one? I would really like to hear from the Safari dev team if they plan to acknowledge and fix this bug.

Comment: @murrayju: Saxon CE,  http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml , and Frameless: http://frameless.io/xslt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any evidence to the contrary, this appears to be a bug in Safari. I've reported this to Apple (`rdar://23207226`), but so far haven't heard anything from them.

The only available workaround is to run the XSLT on some other engine (server side, or perhaps through a 3rd party javascript engine).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug. As a work around you could try to set the namespace you want as well on the `xsl:attribute namespace="urn:test:ns2"`.

Comment: Tried this, and it made no difference. I updated my question to include it. Thanks for the suggestion though. I agree that this looks like a Safari bug.

Comment: What happens if you put the namespace declaration `xmlns:ns2="urn:test:ns2"` too on the `xsl:attribute`?

Comment: Also made no difference. Glad it didn't though, that would have been redundant.